# Syntax error in my yaml file in Rails for some reason

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml

I'm getting the following error message because of a syntax error with my yml file:

```
Psych::SyntaxError: (/home/runner/quaderno/config/locales/emails/es.yml): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token at line 284 column 16
```

The line in question in the yml file looks like is this one:

```
subject: %{document_type} pendiente
```

What is causing this and what is the correct syntax?

Comment: Just wrap it in `""`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In YAML, `%` cannot start a plain scalar because it is an *indicator* (used for directives at the document header), see [relevant part of the spec](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788859).

Your options are:

```yaml
subject: "%{document_type} pendiente" # double-quoted
subject: '%{document_type} pendiente' # single-quoted
subject: >-                           # folded block scalar
  %{document_type} pendiente
subject: |-                           # literal block scalar
  %{document_type} pendiente
```

All of these options have the exactly same semantics. The block scalar types are good for long content or when you don't want to think about *any* problematic characters in your scalar (as double-quoted scalars process escape sequences and single-quoted scalars have `'` as special character).